# Fill an object with the results of every loop iteration in R

Tags: r, loops, object, for-loop, xts

first time asker here. I have recently strated working with R and I hope I could get some help with an issue. The problem is probably easy to solve but I haven't been able to find an answer by myself and my research hasn't been succesful either.

Basically I need to create a single object based on the input of a loop. I have 7 simulated asset returns, these objects contain the results from a simulation I ran. I want to match the columns from every object and form a combined one (i.e. every column 1 forms an object), which will be used for some calculations.
Finally, the result from each iteration should be stored on a single object that has to be available outside the loop for further analysis.

I have created the following loop, the problem is that only the result from the last iteration is being written in the final object.

```
# Initial xts object definition
iteration_returns_combined <- iteration_returns_draft_1


for (i in 2:10){

  # Compose object by extracting the i element of every simulation serie
  matrix_daily_return_iteration <- cbind(xts_simulated_return_asset_1[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_2[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_3[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_4[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_5[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_6[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_7[,i])

  # Transform the matrix to an xts object
  daily_return_iteration_xts <- as.xts(matrix_daily_return_iteration,
                                       order.by = index(optimization_returns))

  # Calculate the daily portfolio returns using the iteration return object
  iteration_returns <- Return.portfolio(daily_return_iteration_xts,
                                        extractWeights(portfolio_optimization))

  # Create a combined object for each iteration of portfolio return
  # This is the object that is needed in the end
  iteration_returns_combined <<- cbind(iteration_returns_draft_combined, 
                                       iteration_returns_draft)

}
```

[iteration_returns_combined_after_loop_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHTmM.jpg)

Could somebody please help me to fix this issue, I would be extremely grateful for any information anyone can provide.

Thanks,
R-Rookie

Comment: Please correct the typo in the last line of your code "<<-". Also, there is no object such as iteration_returns_draft

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working now

Comment: @RajPadmanabhan, that is not a typo. There is such an [assignment operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) in R.

Comment: @Parfait, I realize that now, thanks!

Comment: @Parfait right, I think I previously used it when creating a function, so that a partial result in the function can be used later on another part of the function

Comment: Where in your function is *iteration_returns_draft*? Did you mean *iteration_returns*?

Comment: @Parfait yes. It should have been iteration_returns

Comment: Curious @R_Rookie_2009... you were with me until the end. Did the `sapply` below work?

Comment: @Parfait, I haven't given it a go yet, when I have the chance I'll get back to you. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code, I surmise that the error is in the last line of your for loop.

```
iteration_returns_draft_combined
```

was never defined, so it is assumed to be NULL. Essentially, you only bind columns of the results from each iteration to a NULL object. Hence the output of your last loop is also bound by column to a NULL object, which is what you observe. Try the following:

```
iteration_returns_combined <- cbind(iteration_returns_combined, 
                                   iteration_returns)
```

This should work, hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

Consider `sapply` and avoid expanding an object within a loop:

```
iteration_returns_combined <- sapply(2:10, function(i) {

  # Compose object by extracting the i element of every simulation serie
  matrix_daily_return_iteration <- cbind(xts_simulated_return_asset_1[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_2[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_3[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_4[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_5[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_6[,i],
                                         xts_simulated_return_asset_7[,i])

  # Transform the matrix to an xts object
  daily_return_iteration_xts <- as.xts(matrix_daily_return_iteration,
                                       order.by = index(optimization_returns))

  # Calculate the daily portfolio returns using the iteration return object
  iteration_returns <- Return.portfolio(daily_return_iteration_xts,
                                        extractWeights(portfolio_optimization))
})
```

And if needed to column bind first vector/matrix, do so afterwards:

```
# CBIND INITIAL RUN
iteration_returns_combined <- cbind(iteration_returns_draft_1, iteration_returns_combined)
```